# Routing error | uninitialized constant App::SettingsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with controllers and routes in ruby on rails. I cant figure out what i've done wrong. I appreciate help! I guess its a pleural issue however i'm only a begginer.

Errors says Routing error | uninitialized constant App::SettingsController

Controller:

```
class App::SettingsController < App::BaseController

  def index
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'calendar/index'

  root to: 'visitors#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    invitations: 'users/invitations',
  }

  namespace :app do
    get 'dashboard' => 'dashboards#index',  as: :dashboards
    get 'setting' => 'settings#index',  as: :settings
    get 'report' => 'reports#index',  as: :reports
    resources :residents
    resources :contacts
    resources :users do
      collection do
        get :profile
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

View:

```
app/views/app/settings
app/views/app/settings/index.html.erb
```

Comment: What is the path of the settings_controller and what is the file name?

Comment: @Pavan is correct, this is most likely caused by an incorrect file path / name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrong file name `setting.rb` should be `settings_controller.rb`